# Files with unapproved/unknown licenses when running a gradle project

Tags: java, apache, gradle, netbeans, mifos

I'm trying to run this API: [GitHub link](https://github.com/apache/fineract/tree/develop) as a gradle project in Netbeans. When I build, it fails with this error: **Found 1715 files with unapproved/unknown licenses**.

I would appreciate if you could help me.

[image: build errors]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rat` tasks functionality seems to be implemented by the [Apache RAT (Release Audit Tool) Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/eskatos/creadur-rat-gradle). I do not know or use the plugin, but according to its documentation, the task provides a `failOnError` property, which defaults to true. In the project you linked, the configuration closure for the `rat` task does not change the value of this property. By disabling the automatic failure you should be able to successfully run the build.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I added the `failOnError=false` property and now it builds sucessfully. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Adding the property to file **build.gradle** inside my project filefixed the issue:

```
rat {

...

failOnError = false
```

Comment: Worked for me. I tried this code in my gradle.build file and it was good to go.